# Where are native Windows 8 icons located?

Tags: windows-8, icons, desktop-icons

I'm talking about simple white icons that appears on start screen. I want to use them on shortcuts. So, I need a file or .dll that contains metro icons.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to use them in your own application?  I wouldn't advise doing that since Microsoft no doubt has a copyright on them.

Comment: No, I doesn't have my own app yet. Just to change icons on folders and so on. I've found some icons here C:\Windows\System32\twinui.dll but not what I wanted.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly with these images?

Comment: I have a directory called "Maps" on my desktop and want to set a proper (white) icon. Also I have Restart command shortcut on my start menu and want to set a good icon on it.

Comment: They are called "tiles" now, not icons.

Comment: I'm pretty sure each respective Store App has it's own logo.png file.

Answer (score 15):

They are located in `%windir%\System32\imageres.dll`

Comment: Helped me to set a "My Pictures" icon on my own pictures folder. Thanks.

Comment: This is the same for Windows 10.

Answer (score 9):

While this isn't the "official" icons, there is the alternative of creating them through [Syncfusion's Metro Studio v2](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/metrostudio) (which is currently free):

[image]

> Syncfusion Metro Studio is a collection of over 1700 Metro-style icon
>   templates that can be easily customized to create thousands of unique
>   Metro icons.

There are tons of icons already made, and you can create your own:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! +1

Comment: I can use Photoshop to create any icon I want, or try to find them on google. But I'm looking for just a file with **native Microsoft Windows 8 icons** in c:/windows

Answer (score 4):

There are several files:

- `C:\Windows\System32\DDORes.dll`

[image: Screenshot of DDORes.dll icons]

- `C:\Windows\System32\imageres.dll`

[image: Screenshot of imageres.dll icons]

- `C:\Windows\System32\shell32.dll`

[image: Screenshot of shell32.dll icons]

- `C:\Windows\System32\dmdskres.dll`

[image]

- `C:\Windows\System32\comres.dll`

[image]

- `C:\Windows\System32\mmsres.dll`

[image]

- `C:\Windows\System32\setupapi.dll`

[image]

- `C:\Windows\explorer.exe`

[image]

- `C:\Windows\System32\pifmgr.dll` -> This ones dates back to Win95

[image: Screenshot of pifmgr.dll icons]

Listed are the ones I've found that come included in Windows 8 / Windows 8.1, does anyone know of others?

Comment: This looks like an excellent answer.  It was at -1.  Or did the edit fix a previous issue?

Comment: With Windows 95, 98, ME, I used c:/windows/progman.exe and it was full of the exact icons I need.  I can't find anything similar in Win8

Answer (score 2):

I just found that here: [XAML Icons](http://www.devitep.de/Apps/XamlIcons)

Helped me a lot and is much cheaper than Metro Studio.

[image: Search view]
[image: Random icons]
[image: Icon editor]
[image: XAML Code]

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. Thanks for your answer I removed the salutation as we want answers to stand on their own.

Comment: Nice site you found :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using the **Run** command and the following folder -

```
C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\INetCache\
```

When the folder opens it will be blank, but do a search using ***.ico** and the favicon files should appear.